# Azure AD B2C: Internal error when adding api access to applications

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am receiving an internal B2C service error when attempting to add api access to the appplication in b2c tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will mostly happen when someone modifies that service principal of the application from outside Azure AD B2C and set property appRoleAssignmentRequired = true on the SP object.

To fix the issue please change the property appRoleAssignmentRequired = false.
You can use https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net